# Is it okay to put business(custom) validate in the DTO?

Tags: java, validation

```
@Getter
public class PolicyRequestDto {

    @Getter
    @Builder
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class InsertPolicyRequest {
        @NotNull(message = "need typeNo")
        private Integer typeNo;
        private String typeDescription;
        private Long volume;
        private Integer retryCnt;
        private Integer authTime;

        public InsertPolicyRequest insertValidate() {

            PolicyTypeEnum policyEnumList = new PolicyTypeEnum();
            Stream<Integer> volumeList = policyEnumList.getVolumeList().stream();
            Stream<Integer> authTimeList = policyEnumList.getAuthTimeList().stream();
            Stream<Integer> retryCntList = policyEnumList.getRetryCntList().stream();

            switch (Objects.requireNonNull(typeNo, "no typeNo")) {
                case 0 :
                    // case 0
                    break;
                case 1 :
                    // case 1
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    // case 2
                    break;
                default : throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error");
            }

            return this;
        }

        public PolicyEntity toEntity () {
            return PolicyEntity.builder()
                    .typeNo(typeNo)
                    .volume(volume)
                    .retryCnt(retryCnt)
                    .authTime(authTime)
                    .build();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public PolicyResponseDto.CommonResponse addWifiServicePolicy(@Valid PolicyRequestDto.InsertPolicyRequest insertRequest) {

        insertRequest.insertValidate();
        PolicyEntity policyEntity = insertRequest.toEntity();

        ...

        return ...
}
```

If there is a validation required by that service that cannot be done with the @Validated annotation, can it be done in the DTO?

Right now, the verification process is at a level that varies depending on the input parameters, for example, code. The service wants to perform business logic only with data that has passed this verification. It's annoying that validation code is put at the top of each method, but I think it's necessary code.

Is there any problem with doing this in the DTO?

p.s I want to make a service object independent of the controller, so that there is no problem even if only the service is separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your custom validation annotation.

```
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyConstraintValidator.class)
public @interface MyConstraint {

    String message() default "default error message";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

This annotation works on the field or method level. The validator must implement [ConstraintValidator](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html).

```
public class MyConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyConstraint, Integer> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Integer typeNo, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        PolicyTypeEnum policyEnumList = new PolicyTypeEnum();
        Stream<Integer> volumeList = policyEnumList.getVolumeList().stream();
        Stream<Integer> authTimeList = policyEnumList.getAuthTimeList().stream();
        Stream<Integer> retryCntList = policyEnumList.getRetryCntList().stream();

        switch (Objects.requireNonNull(typeNo, "no typeNo")) {
            case 0 :
                // case 0
                break;
            case 1 :
                // case 1
                break;
            case 2 :
                // case 2
                break;
            default :
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

If you need to access data from other fields, you need to update the annotation to be applicable on the type level - `@Target( { ElementType.TYPE })`, and accordingly change the validator to work with the type - `InsertPolicyRequest`:

```
public class MyConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyConstraint, InsertPolicyRequest> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(InsertPolicyRequest request, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        PolicyTypeEnum policyEnumList = new PolicyTypeEnum();
        Stream<Integer> volumeList = policyEnumList.getVolumeList().stream();
        Stream<Integer> authTimeList = policyEnumList.getAuthTimeList().stream();
        Stream<Integer> retryCntList = policyEnumList.getRetryCntList().stream();

        switch (Objects.requireNonNull(request.getTypeNo(), "no typeNo")) {
            case 0 :
                // case 0
                break;
            case 1 :
                // case 1
                break;
            case 2 :
                // case 2
                break;
            default :
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Check this [guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator) as well.

**Edit:** It's doable with a single annotation. Have an interface which will take care of extracting common data, let's call it `PolicyRequestData`.

```
public interface PolicyRequestData {

  Integer getTypeNo();
  String getTypeName();
}
```

Then change the annotation from above to work on the type level and rename it to `MyCommonConstraint`. Update `ConstraintValidator` to work with `PolicyRequestData` instead of concrete class.

```
public class MyCommonConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyCommonConstraint, PolicyRequestData> {

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(PolicyRequestData request, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
    PolicyTypeEnum policyEnumList = new PolicyTypeEnum();
    Stream<Integer> volumeList = policyEnumList.getVolumeList().stream();
    Stream<Integer> authTimeList = policyEnumList.getAuthTimeList().stream();
    Stream<Integer> retryCntList = policyEnumList.getRetryCntList().stream();

    switch (Objects.requireNonNull(request.getTypeNo(), "no typeNo")) {
      case 0 :
        // case 0
        break;
      case 1 :
        // case 1
        break;
      case 2 :
        // case 2
        break;
      default :
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Like this the annotation will work on **any** class implementing `PolicyRequestData`.

```
@MyCommonConstraint
public class InsertPolicyRequest implements PolicyRequestData {

  private Integer typeNo;
  private String typeName;

  @Override
  public Integer getTypeNo() {
    return this.typeNo;
  }

  @Override
  public String getTypeName() {
    return this.typeName;
  }

  //setters, if needed
}
```

`UpdatePolicyRequest` is absolutely identical, except for class name.

If you need to validate classes with specific data extend the interface.

```
public interface SpecificPolicyRequestData extends PolicyRequestData {

  String getOtherData();
}
```

Have the specific class implement it and create annotation to work with this interface. Then apply both annotations on the class(if both validations are needed):

```
@MyCommonConstraint
@MySpecificConstraint
public class SomeSpecificPolicyRequest implements SpecificPolicyRequestData {

  @Override
  public Integer getTypeNo() {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public String getTypeName() {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public String getOtherData() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Your suggestion is a valid method, but I have poorly explained the example.

Multiple parameters must be entered in "one validation method".

This is the process of switch operation based on these several parameters.

I can say that I can throw it as an object, but I have the same fields that need validation, but the objects I can throw are all different objects...

Comment: Sample Required parameters: type, typeName, type Use... etc
The object that owns it:
InsertPolicyRequest ,
UpdatePolicyRequest

Since only one object can be assigned to an annotation, I don't think it will be usable unless you create two annotations. Is that right?

Comment: @바보린 So you have 2 classes - InsertPolicyRequest and UpdatePolicyRequest, which have the same fields and need to go through the same validation process. Did i understand correctly?

Comment: The answer was late.
What you understand is correct. However, the number of classes may increase, but let's say there are two.

A two-class model of similar (close to identical) fields.

Comment: @바보린 Check edit.

Comment: Thanks for your new help. Let's try the method you mentioned.